# optimizeWaypoints option in ngmap

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs, ng-map

Hello I am using angularjs and ngmap I want to display a direction going through different points in an optimized way ie the direction which leads to the shortest path

I am using the option optimized way to do so but that doesn't seem to work , I check the documentation of ngmap I haven't found any reference about this

please find the code :

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
  <ng-map  center="current-position">
        <directions
              draggable="true"
              panel="directions-panel"
              travel-mode="DRIVING"
              origin={{adresse1}}
              waypoints={{likedLabels}}
              optimizeWaypoints="true"
              destination={{adresse2}}>
            </directions>
  </ng-map>
```

linkedLabels is an array which look as the following:

```
[
  {
    "location": {
      "lat": 50.62924999999999,
      "lng": 3.057256000000052
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "lat": 48.85661400000001,
      "lng": 2.3522219000000177
    }
  },
  {
    "location": {
      "lat": 48.117266,
      "lng": -1.6777925999999752
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: as far as I understand, optimizeWaypoints is a Google Maps property and has not been exposed in ngMap (unfortunately). If you want to optimise your waypoints, you'll probably have to use a different solution or make a feature request (https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured it by now, but since it's still not in the docs - you can use it like so:

```
<directions
    ...
    optimize-waypoints="true"
</directions>
```